# After running ssh-add when I'm trying to access ssh on aws I'm getting "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, server, chmod

I was trying to add ssh key for GitHub and made some changes in the ssh folder as I was getting the error during ssh-add command.
After when I tried logging in on the server through ssh I get the error

`user@<IP Address> Permission denied (publickey).`

This is the new AWS instance and nothing has been set up for now. just tried adding SSH keys for GitHub authentications.

First I created the ssh public key for GitHub.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Then during ssh-add command, I was getting the permission denied error, so I made some permission changes for ssh keys.

`sudo chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh/`

Then tried ssh-add

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

and when I list the files in ~/.ssh/ directory I get this:

`ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? authorized_keys
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa.pub`

and then after exiting the server, I was not able to log in again through SSH.

I'm not able to connect to the server, So any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
sudo chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh/
```

You are giving the permissions to `.ssh` by this command and that restricts the login to check authorized keys.

**Change it** to `sudo chmod -R 400 ~/.ssh/*` and that should fix the problem.

Also,

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

This is coming up because you might forgot to start the `ssh agent`. To start the ssh-agent in the background

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Yes, this is what went wrong. I'll keep that in mind from now on.